# Zoom in/out image with Scrolling on the image or pressing +/- button

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, razor

I have some razor pages that each contain 1~3 images .

I want that if i hovered on them and scrolled , zoom in or out depend on scroll direction or if i pressed a
 + / - button zoom or zoom out the image .

also i want to apply to all images without considering how many images does the page have . i mean be appliable using querySelectorAll or something like that

something like googlemap zoom but for images (jpg/png/...)

better to all be written in JavaScript

is there any library that has mentioned options ?

is there any website which has a tutorial tutorial ?

one i found was https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/ but there is no   +/- button suport

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I'd take is to dynamically created and inject the buttons with event listeners to zoom in/out on the images. Below is an example of what I mean, let me know if you need help understanding any parts of it,

```js
const scaleUp = image =>
{
  const scale = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('scaler'));
  image.style.transform = `scale(${scale + 0.1})`;
  image.setAttribute('scaler', Math.max(0, scale + 0.1));
};

const scaleDown = image =>
{
  const scale = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('scaler'));
  image.style.transform = `scale(${scale - 0.1})`;
  image.setAttribute('scaler', Math.max(0, scale - 0.1));
};

(async () =>
{
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  
  const buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
  buttonContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
  buttonContainer.style.bottom = '15px';
  buttonContainer.style.width = '100%';
  buttonContainer.style.textAlign = 'center';
  
  for (let image of images)
  {
    await image.decode();
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.position = 'relative';
    container.style.display = 'inline-block';
    container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    container.style.width = image.clientWidth;
    container.style.height = image.clientHeight;
    
    const containerImage = image.cloneNode();
    containerImage.setAttribute('scaler', '1');
    
    const plusButton = document.createElement('button');
    const minusButton = document.createElement('button');
    plusButton.textContent = '+';
    minusButton.textContent = '-';
    
    plusButton.addEventListener('click', () => scaleUp(containerImage), true);
    minusButton.addEventListener('click', () => scaleDown(containerImage), true);
    
    container.addEventListener('wheel', event =>
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      if (event.deltaY < 0) 
        scaleUp(containerImage);
      else if (event.deltaY > 0)
        scaleDown(containerImage);
    }, true);
    
    const imageButtonContainer = buttonContainer.cloneNode();
    imageButtonContainer.appendChild(minusButton);
    imageButtonContainer.appendChild(plusButton);
    
    container.appendChild(containerImage);
    container.appendChild(imageButtonContainer);
    image.replaceWith(container);
  }
})();
```

```html
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/001.png" />
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/002.png" />
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/003.png" />
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/004.png" />
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/005.png" />
<img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/006.png" />
```

Comment: exactly , this is what i was searching for but i need to zoom and zoom aout with wheel as well

Comment: Aha missed that part, updated to scroll according to mouse direction on the `wheel` event. Please see if this solution works for you and accept the answer if it does :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar on a previous project of mine, perhaps try use the following resource as a guideline;

https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-zoom-into-an-image-on-scroll/

You could try using the script they suggest:

```
<script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/   i was thinking about sth like this also supported with + / - button

Comment: Oh i see, this looks like something more down the lines of what you're looking for. Hope it works :)